# Using ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 cannot seem to test ListView contents

Tags: android, mockito, android-testing

I have the following test code. I am trying to test whether a list is being populated from SQLite database.

```
public class ViewIssuesActivityTest extends BaseActivityTest<ViewIssuesActivity>{

  private List<Issue> issues;

  public ViewIssuesActivityTest() {
    super(ViewIssuesActivity.class);
  }

  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    issues = new ArrayList<Issue>();
    issues.add(new Issue("Trial","Desc","Location","ImagePath"));
    IssueRepository issueRepository = mock(IssueRepository.class);


    doAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
        @Override
        public List<Issue> answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            return issues;
        }
    }).when(issueRepository).getIssues();
    activity.setIssueRepository(issueRepository);

  }

  public void testNumberOfIssuesRecorded() {
    ListView listView = (ListView) activity.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    assertEquals(1, listView.getCount());
  }
}
```

My BaseActivityTest code is:

```
public class BaseActivityTest<T extends Activity> extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<T> {

 protected T activity;

 public BaseActivityTest(Class<T> activityClass) {
     super(activityClass);
 }

 @Override
 protected void setUp() throws Exception {
     activity = getActivity();
 }
}
```

My ViewIssuesActivity is as follows:

```
public class ViewIssuesActivity extends ListActivity{

 private IssueRepository issueRepository;


 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(com.change.kranti.R.layout.issues);
 issueRepository = new IssueRepository(getApplicationContext());

 List<Issue> issues = new ArrayList<Issue>();
 issues = issueRepository.getIssues();
 ArrayAdapter<Issue> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Issue>(this,
  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, issues);

 setListAdapter(adapter);
 }

}
```

The issue is I get error: expected<1> got <0>

I think the issue is the onCreate method is getting called before the issueRepository is created.
I want to mock the IssueRepository and test my list getting populated.

What is the issue with my code or is there a better way to test this functionality.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. The issue is that the `onCreate` method gets called before the mock `issueRepository` gets injected. When you call `getActivity` in the context of an `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`, all the usual life cycle methods get called (i.e., `onCreate`, `onStart`, and `onResume`). When your test code calls `setIssueRepository`, it's already too late, the issues have been fetched from the repository.

The best solution I know in this kind of case is to use dependency injection, whether by hand or using a DI framework.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to do.

You can't run two tests simultaneously against the same class. The ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 class is essentially a controller and wrapper for the Activity under test, but it can only control a single Activity, and you can't control the same Activity with multiple instances of ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.

To set up an app for test-driven development, try to use as many POJOs (Plain Old Java Objects) as you can. Limit the Activity testing to stuff such as sending Intents or integration between POJOs that you can mock.

ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 is a JUnit TestCase subclass, but it has limitations.

Comment: But I am not running two tests simultaneously. I have a issueRepository that talks to the DB and the ViewIssueActivity reads the items from the DB to the list. I need to test this functionality.